# shift:both_capslock disables normal shift behavior

Tags: linux, x11, xkb

I set the xkb option shift:both_capslock (because I also use caps:escape) but this seems to have disabled the normal behavior of the shift key. How can I get that normal behavior back while still allowing the double press.

I used to do this in gnome, but I am trying out sway.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, and an examination of xev suggests pressing shift produces a Shift_L key press event, and a Caps_Lock key release event (!). Does this seem to be the same behavior you've encountered?

Comment: @gandalf3 Due to this and some other issues I switched back to gnome so I cannot test. Thanks for the xev output though!

Answer (score 0):

I eventually got it to work the way I want with [sxhkd](https://github.com/baskerville/sxhkd) and xdotool, as follows

```
shift + ~Shift_{L,R} 
    xdotool key Caps_Lock
```

Answer (score 0):

I use the following settings and I find that the shift key functions as expected

```
# Make unmodified Caps Lock an additional Esc,
# but Shift + Caps Lock behaves like regular Caps Lock.
setxkbmap -option 'caps:escape_shifted_capslock'

# Both Shift together enable Caps Lock.
setxkbmap -option 'shift:both_capslock'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try [interception-tools](https://gitlab.com/interception/linux/tools) with [both-shift-capslock](https://gitlab.com/zeertzjq/interception-both-shift-capslock), although interception-tools may [cause the keyboard LEDs to stop functioning under some circumstances](https://gitlab.com/interception/linux/tools/-/issues/30).